# Looking for an alternative to eval

Tags: ruby, eval

I'm new to ruby however it isn't really that drastic of a change coming from perl, anyways 've written a simple script to convert my gobs of perl Data::Dumper output into yaml configs, my problem is I'm using eval to accomplish this and seeing as I may like others to use this script one day I would like to eliminate eval for something more sane.

example:

input file contains

```
$VAR1 = { 'object' => { 'some_key' => 'some_value' } }
```

method to read it in

```
# read in file here ...
eval( stringified_file )
print $VAR1.to_yaml
```

output

```
object:
  some_key: some_value
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

On the Perl side you can output your data structures to YAML (I like YAML::Syck for this), and then read the data in as YAML on the Ruby side.  That way you won't need to do an eval.

Comment: I don't have the luxury of doing that, the other problem is that there are literally hundreds of scripts preforming this same maneuver. We use them as configuration files unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm.  Is saving the Dumper exports as config files an architectural decision you can revisit?  It seems like a bad idea in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

If for you're unable to change the source application to output YAML, use [Kernel#load](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005940):

```
require 'yaml'

load 'dumped_file', true
puts $VAR1.to_yaml
```